# AWS Codebuild: Monorepo and multiple builds?

Tags: aws-lambda, devops, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have an AWS CodePipeline which uses CodeBuild as the build step and deploys Lambda functions. This pipeline is triggered upon any commit on the development branch which houses multiple Lambda functions. Right now, since all these Lambdas use the same pipeline, they have the same build job as well.

The problem is, what happens in case one of my Lambdas has a different requirement in the build step (say installing a library). Is there any way to trigger a different build job for a specific Lambda? I am guessing this delves into the age-old issue of Codepipeline unable to deal with monorepo, but any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You could integrate change detection for your lambda functions. The only thing you need is that you need to check out the source separately in the job so you got the .git folder (see: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=251732).

Afterwards you can easily check with git which lambda function was actually changed and run your pre-build commands based on the result.